# Prime ideal generated with polynomial of degree 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K=\{p\in \mathbb{Q}_n[x]\ |\ p(0)\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be a commutative ring. I have to check if an ideal $I=\{p\in K\ |\ p(0)=0\}$ of $K$ is prime or not.

I would suppose that $I$ is a prime ideal. Let $I=\langle p\rangle=\{pq\ |\ q\in K\}, p\in K.$

Then, if $deg(p)>0,$ we have $deg(pq)=deg(p)+deg(q)>0,$ so every polynomial in $I$ has degree bigger than $0,$ which is a contradiction because $deg(0)=0.$

If $deg(p)=0,$ then $p=c\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Any polynomial in $I$ we can represent using $p.$ Can we then say that $I$ is a prime ideal or a generator cannot be polynomial with degree $0?$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}_n$?

Comment: The set of polynomials $p$ such that $deg(p)\leqslant n$ and coefficients are from $\mathbb{Q}.$

Comment: The formula $\deg (p\cdot q)=\deg p + \deg q$ is not valid when one of $p$ or $q$ is the zero polynomial. There is no contradiction when you assume $\deg p > 0$ because $q=0$ is in $K$ and hence $I$.

Comment: Polynomials of degree at most $n$ do not form a ring (unless $n=0$).